# BFS detecting cycles where it should not be

Tags: c++

I have implemented a BFS algorithm to detect cycles in a graph, this is the following code:

```
            void hasCycle(node *root,string start){  
            if(root->visted){
                if(root->name == start) cout << "Has cycle" << endl;
                else return;
            }
            root->visted = true;
            int ind;
            for(ind = 0; ind < root->adj.size(); ind++)
                hasCycle(root->adj[ind], start);
            root->visted = false;
            }
```

Where start is the starting node.
where node is the following struct:

```
            struct node{
                string name;
                bool   visted;
                vector <node *> adj;
            };
```

This is the Graph that I have constructed:

```
            Graph *grp = new Graph();
            grp->addVertex("A");
            grp->addVertex("B");
            grp->addVertex("C");

            grp->addEdge("A","B");
            grp->addEdge("B","A");
            grp->addEdge("A","C");
            grp->addEdge("C","A");
```

The output is:
                Has cycle
                Has cycle
                Has cycle

The correct output is nothing since there is no cycle. I have spent a lot of time trying to debug this, please help!

note: This is not a directed graph so I want them to be double edges

Comment: Isn't A => B => A a cycle? And A => C => A?

Comment: @amit This is not a directed graph so i want them to be double edges

Comment: For undirected graph, for every connected component of size `|V|`, if there are more then `|V|-1` edges, there is a cycle in the graph

Answer (score 1):

I presume you want a cycle of size 3 or more in an undirected graph. In that case, you should ignore the parent in the BFS traversal when checking for 'visited'.

Comment: no i dont want a cycle of size 3, it shouldnt output anything since there is no cycle (in an undirected graph)

Comment: I am saying that you have to remove a cycle of 'size 2' by checking the parent. Hence you are looking for a cycle of size 3 or more. This is an undirected graph, the parent is always the child's neighbour (2-cycle with respect to your implementation).

Answer (score 0):

Some Issues here:

1. BFS does not for well for finding cycles in graph. for example have a look at the undirected graph `A->B->C->A`, the BFS from `A` will discover first `A`, and then `B` and `C`, and will stop there - without detecting the loop.
2. Your implementation should NOT use an undirected edge twice, and your implementation does, for every `u`, `v` - it uses both `u->v` and `v->u`(*)
3. Your implementation only detects loops through `start`, it will miss "laso" loops [loops that are reachable from `start`, but do not contain `start`].

**A possible solution:** Note that for a not directed graph, for each connected component of size `|V|`, if there are more then `|V|-1` edges - the component is not a [tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28graph_theory%29), and the graph has at list one cycle [since tree in a directed graph is the maximal structure without cycles].

So, in order to find if there is a cycle - you can just find all connected components [BFS is good for it], and check if each such component contains more then `|V|-1` edges.

(*)2 is debateable actually - but in standard BFS implementation - there is no point to do it, since BFS is for discovery of nodes, and if you already used an edge - both vertices connected to it are already discovered.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with using the edge twice. You can always build an undirected graph from a directed graph implementation.